# Missing Field or Method

Tags: go

```
var client := http.Client
```

For whatever reason this code is giving the error message missing variable or initialization. Can someone enlighten me on why? I'm not understanding what I have done wrong.

Comment: try `var client = http.Client`. `client := http.Client` is equivalent to `var client = http.Client`. Your usage is invalid syntactically.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work. It just populated 4 new errors

Comment: Since you're creating an `http.Client` you need the `{}` at the end since you're making a struct. See my answer.

Comment: `var client http.Client` or `client := http.Client{}` or `var client = http.Client{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Go we use `:=` or `var =` for initializing variables. In your case you can re-write it to be:

```golang
var client = http.Client{}
```

or

```golang
client := http.Client{}
```

Either of these will trigger [type inference](https://go.dev/tour/basics/14) of the variable. You can use `var` with a type to explicitly declare a type as well. In your case if you wanted to enforce the type you could write:

```golang
var client http.Client = http.Client{}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for the most part but showed some about four new errors elsewhere.  I'ma scrap everything and start from scratch again but keeping the var client http.Client